# Qt installation

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, qt, qt4, codeblocks

I am completely confused in installing `Qt`.

Do I need to download both `Qt creator` and `Qt SDK` or `Qt.exe`?

I have `Visual Studio 2010` and `Code::Blocks`in my PC. So, how can I link if any one of the `Qt XXXX` listed above with `VS-2010` or with `Code::Blocks`?

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download QT creator from http://qt-project.org/downloads for windows you will get a .exe (you will find different .exe for VS Studio and mingw, so you can use what you prefer), once you install it you got

- Qt libraries, prebuilt for a particular development platform (operating system
  and compiler)
- Qt Creator integrated development environment (IDE)
- Basic development tools, prebuilt for a particular development platform
- Documentation

Some more help.

You can start Qt Creator directly after the installation by selecting the option
on the last page of the installation program. You can start most of
the development tools, such as GUI designers, compilers, and debuggers
directly from Qt Creator. You can also access the installed documentation and
example applications from Qt Creator.

You can open most example applications in the Qt Creator Welcome mode to build
and run them. Additional examples can be opened by browsing
(install_dir)/(version)/(compiler)/examples.

To develop a Qt application, you need to set up a project. Qt Creator contains
wizards that guide you step-by-step through the project creation process. The
wizards prompt you to enter the settings needed for a particular type of project
and create the necessary files for you. To start, select File > New File or
Project.

The wizards create projects that use the Qt build tool, qmake. It is a
cross-platform system for build automation that helps simplify the build process
for development projects across different platforms. You can modify the build
and run settings for qmake projects in the Qt Creator Projects mode.

Qt Creator provides support for building, running, and deploying Qt applications
for different target platforms, or using different compilers, debuggers, or
Qt versions. Kits define the tools, device type and other settings to use when
building and running your project.

The Qt installation program adds the installed Qt version
((install_dir)/(version)/(compiler)/bin/qmake) to Qt Creator and creates a kit
that specifies the installed Qt version and compiler. To use the kit, add it for
your project in the Qt Creator Projects mode. Then select the kit in the Kit
selector before you build or run the project.

To compile C++ Qt applications by some other means, add
(install_dir)/(version)/(compiler)/include to your build tool's search path
for include files, and (install_dir)/(version)/(compiler)/lib to the search
path for libraries.

Answer (score 1):

To work with Visual Studio 2010, you can download the installer "Qt 5.0.1 for Windows 32-bit (VS 2010, 481 MB)", or just download the source code and build it yourself (you'll need to do that if you want 64-bit versions of the libraries).

"Qt Creator" is Qt's IDE, so you don't need that. You just need the "Qt Library" to use Qt with other IDEs. For Visual Studio, you'll also want to download the "Visual Studio Add-in," which allows you to view Qt data structures in the debugger.

The free downloads are available at [qt-project](http://qt-project.org/downloads). Commercial downloads are on [digia](http://qt.digia.com/Try-Qt-Now/).